# nl2br converts true to int and false to empty string

Tags: php, php-5.6

I am using PHP Version 5.6.25. The following code is all that's needed to replicate the issue.

```
$data['foo'] = true;
$data['bar'] = false;
var_dump($data);
$data['foo'] = nl2br($data['foo']);
$data['bar'] = nl2br($data['bar']);
array_walk_recursive($data, "filter");
var_dump($data);
```

This gives the following result.

```
array (size=2)
  'foo' => boolean true
  'bar' => boolean false
array (size=2)
  'foo' => string '1' (length=1)
  'bar' => string '' (length=0)
```

Is this a PHP bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: why would you ever want to use nl2br() on boolean values?

Comment: `var_dump(nl2br(true));` //string(1) "1" its nothing to do with array_walk

Comment: @rtfm The array I'm running this on is mixed. I should check that the value is a string before using it. That would fix this issue for me. I still think it's unexpected behavior.

Comment: @rtfm Ah, you're right, let me edit the question.

Comment: makes sense for nl2br() to do a string conversion. you could change filter function to check first

Comment: @rtfm yep, you can post as answer and I'll accept. I guess I should watch what I pass to functions.

Comment: It's not unexpected behaviour. `var_dump((string)true, (string)false);` and you'll see the same [documented behaviour](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the manual [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

> string nl2br ( string $string [, bool $is_xhtml = true ] )

nl2br expects a string as an input, casting a boolean to a string returns 1 for true and "" for false; so no surprises that's what you get in this case.

In your filter function you can check the variable type before deciding how to filter it.

Comment: No, casting a boolean to a string returns `1` or `''` for `true` and `false` respectively. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

Comment: @Sammitch thanks for the correction, feel free to edit hte answer to make it better